# Trigger.io on iOS 7 hangs at launch image

Tags: ios7, trigger.io

I just updated my trigger.io app to use the latest stable platform version (v2.0.1) so that it would hopefully work well on iOS 7. Unfortunately now it hangs on the launch image. The error I get on the iPhone console is below. Any ideas on how to get this working?

```
Oct  1 19:52:42 Strax mobile_installation_proxy[235] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Please include the kCFBundleIdentifierKey in the options dictionary when installing an app.
Oct  1 19:52:42 Strax mobile_installation_proxy[235] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installing app for existing placeholder (null)
Oct  1 19:52:42 Strax installd[62] <Notice>: 0x25d000 handle_install_for_ls: Install of "/var/mobile/Media/PublicStaging/device-ios.app" requested by mobile_installation_proxy
Oct  1 19:52:42 Strax installd[62] <Notice>: 0x25d000 MobileInstallationInstall_Server: Installing app com.redacted.redacted
Oct  1 19:52:43 Strax securityd[79] <Error>: OCSPResponse: now > latestNextUpdate
Oct  1 19:52:43 Strax SpringBoard[33] <Warning>: Killing com.redacted.redacted for termination assertion
Oct  1 19:52:43 Strax installd[62] <Notice>: 0x25d000 install_application: Performing developer delta patch
Oct  1 19:52:43 Strax com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.redacted.redacted[0x9168][331]) <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.redacted.redacted[0x9168]) Exited: Killed: 9
Oct  1 19:52:43 Strax backboardd[28] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.redacted.redacted[0x9168]' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed: 9
Oct  1 19:52:43 Strax installd[62] <Notice>: 0x25d000 MobileInstallationInstall_Server: Staging: 0.05s; Waiting: 0.00s; Installation: 0.53s; LS Sync: 0.00s; Overall: 0.58s
Oct  1 19:52:43 Strax lsd[75] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Updating identifier store
Oct  1 19:52:43 Strax SpringBoard[33] <Error>: libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:835: nike-ipod is static and will never generate a notification
Oct  1 19:52:43 Strax SpringBoard[33] <Error>: libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:835: still-camera is static and will never generate a notification
Oct  1 19:52:43 Strax SpringBoard[33] <Error>: libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:835: magnetometer is static and will never generate a notification
Oct  1 19:52:43 Strax SpringBoard[33] <Error>: libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:835: any-telephony is static and will never generate a notification
Oct  1 19:52:43 Strax SpringBoard[33] <Error>: libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:835: stand-alone-contacts is static and will never generate a notification
Oct  1 19:52:51 Strax MobileStorageMounter[350] <Error>: 0x3d85e18c digest_disk_image: Could not open /var/run/mobile_image_mounter/3zeNth.dmg: No such file or directory
Oct  1 19:52:51 Strax MobileStorageMounter[350] <Error>: 0x3d85e18c reload_mount_map: /Developer - could not create digest
Oct  1 19:52:51 Strax mobile_storage_proxy[349] <Error>: 0x3d85e18c handle_lookup_image: Entry 2 of 4 did not have a digest
Oct  1 19:52:51 Strax MobileStorageMounter[350] <Error>: 0x3d85e18c handle_mount_disk_image: A disk image of type Developer is already mounted
Oct  1 19:52:51 Strax mobile_storage_proxy[349] <Error>: MobileStorageMount:355 Could not extract mount path from response message
Oct  1 19:52:51 Strax mobile_storage_proxy[349] <Error>: 0x3d85e18c handle_mount_image: Could not mount the disk image
Oct  1 19:52:51 Strax mobile_storage_proxy[349] <Error>: 0x3d85e18c main: Could not mount the image
Oct  1 19:52:51 Strax com.apple.debugserver-300.2[351] <Warning>: debugserver-300.2 for armv7.
Oct  1 19:52:51 Strax com.apple.debugserver-300.2[351] <Warning>: Connecting to com.apple.debugserver service...
Oct  1 19:52:51 Strax com.apple.debugserver-300.2[351] <Warning>: Got a connection, waiting for process information for launching or attaching.
Oct  1 19:52:54 Strax assistantd[352] <Notice>: connection 4 total: 1, connected: 0, added new subflow [cid=1, state=Waiting, ifindex=7]
Oct  1 19:52:54 Strax awdd[353] <Error>: CoreLocation: CLClient is deprecated. Will be obsolete soon.
Oct  1 19:52:54 Strax assistantd[352] <Notice>: connection 4 total: 1, connected: 1, new connected subflow [cid=1, state=Connected, ifindex=7, preferred, mp_capable]
Oct  1 19:52:54 Strax assistantd[352] <Notice>: connection 4 total: 2, connected: 1, added new subflow [cid=2, state=Waiting, ifindex=2]
Oct  1 19:52:54 Strax securityd[79] <Error>: OCSPResponse: now > latestNextUpdate
Oct  1 19:52:54 Strax securityd[79] <Error>: OCSPResponse: now > latestNextUpdate
Oct  1 19:52:55 Strax securityd[79] <Error>: OCSPResponse: now + maxAge > latestNextUpdate, using latestNextUpdate
Oct  1 19:52:55 Strax com.apple.debugserver-300.2[351] <Warning>: About to launch process for bundle ID: com.redacted.redacted
Oct  1 19:52:55 Strax securityd[79] <Error>: OCSPResponse: now > latestNextUpdate
Oct  1 19:52:55 Strax kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[354] Container: /private/var/mobile/Applications/1150A554-1046-4DB4-BA37-AC55DA01DED5 (sandbox)
Oct  1 19:52:55 Strax com.apple.debugserver-300.2[351] <Warning>: In completion handler, got pid for bundle id, pid: 354.
Oct  1 19:52:55 Strax com.apple.debugserver-300.2[351] <Warning>: Got a connection, launched process /Developer/usr/bin/debugserver.
Oct  1 19:53:03 Strax Forge[354] <Warning>: [INFO] New app version, removing any reload update files.
Oct  1 19:53:03 Strax kernel[0] <Debug>: 004804.545582 wlan.A[652] AppleBCMWLANNetManager::checkRealTimeTraffic():  now 4804.545565708 num entries 4
Oct  1 19:53:03 Strax kernel[0] <Debug>: 004804.545628 wlan.A[653] AppleBCMWLANCore::dumpWmeCounters():  per TIDs tx counters: 16180 12261 0 0 0 6379 234 0, per TIDs rx counters: 50102 0 0 0 0 0 76 0 
Oct  1 19:53:03 Strax kernel[0] <Debug>: 004804.545668 wlan.A[654] AppleBCMWLANCore::dumpWmeCounters():                AWDL: Tx 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0,                   Rx: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
Oct  1 19:53:03 Strax Forge[354] <Warning>: [INFO] Checking for reload update
Oct  1 19:53:04 Strax Forge[354] <Warning>: [INFO] creating link from /var/mobile/Applications/1150A554-1046-4DB4-BA37-AC55DA01DED5/Library/Application Support/Forge/assets-D653E065-1D29-4DCD-9D75-1E5A5B798680/forge to ../../../../device-ios.app/assets/forge
Oct  1 19:53:04 Strax Forge[354] <Warning>: [INFO] creating link from /var/mobile/Applications/1150A554-1046-4DB4-BA37-AC55DA01DED5/Library/Application Support/Forge/assets-D653E065-1D29-4DCD-9D75-1E5A5B798680/src to ../../../../device-ios.app/assets/src
Oct  1 19:53:04 Strax Forge[354] <Warning>: [INFO] Loading default page in webview.
Oct  1 19:53:04 Strax Forge[354] <Warning>: [INFO] No reload update available.
Oct  1 19:53:04 Strax Forge[354] <Warning>: [INFO] Loading local url in webview: file:///var/mobile/Applications/1150A554-1046-4DB4-BA37-AC55DA01DED5/Library/Application%20Support/Forge/assets-D653E065-1D29-4DCD-9D75-1E5A5B798680/src/index.html
Oct  1 19:53:05 Strax Forge[354] <Warning>: [INFO] Registering for parse push notifications, subscribing to default channel.
Oct  1 19:53:05 Strax Forge[354] <Warning>: [DEBUG] Returning to javascript: {
        event = "internal.connectionStateChange";
        params =     {
            connected = 1;
            wifi = 1;
        };
    }
Oct  1 19:53:11 Strax lockdownd[51] <Notice>: 002c1000 _select_socket: receive secure message timeout!
Oct  1 19:53:20 Strax cplogd[341] <Warning>: Exiting.
```